# Twitter Bootstrap Navigation Icon Loader

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

All of the icons on my navigation menu load fine, but one of the icons doesn't load on a mobile device until the menu is clicked open, then it will load a few seconds later. Please [check here and click button to open menu.](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=macmetro.com) I appreciate any help. The icon in question is called Repair and it's a wrench icon. For some reason, Responsinator renders the site like a desktop does. Please view the site on a mobile phone/tablet so you can see what I'm talking about. Thanks, and free virtual nachos for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to the fact that you have linked a font awesome css not default glyphicon which comes with the default bootstrap.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Better use `"fa fa-wrench"` instead of `glyphicon glyphicon-wrench`